# Backing up Windows 7 clean installation for restore purposes

Tags: windows-7, windows-backup

All these cheap terabytes are giving me headaches. I have few multi TB drives at home and most of them are over 50% full, and now I think my W7 machine needs a re-haul.

I'm from the old school way of doing those things, unless I format the drive I don't think I can call it a clean install. The notion of deleting all these programs, and the notion of backing up all the data on system drive makes me nauseous.

But what I really want to know is - do we have a software that could make a image from my clean installation ?

This is basically what I'm looking for:

- I install the Windows on a clean drive
- I set up all the settings, preferences, bookmarks, programs
- back it up somewhere, somehow - so the next time my computer gets sluggish and slow, I just revert back to that state?

Don't say System Restore, I have nothing but bad experience with that tool...

Comment: Why can't you use any of the 100's of system imaging softwares out there?

Comment: Yes the software exists.  There are free and paid dozens upon dozens of choices.  I won't provide recomendations because sotware recomendations are not on topic ( and this question has been asked before multiple times )

Comment: Maybe you just want some harddrive space back?  Much simpler to run [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.sourceforge.net/) and see what's using the space.  Not sure what that warrants a clean OS install.